# How to derive spring potential formula from Hooke's law?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, spring

I found this answer in another forum:
\begin{align}
W&=\int \mathbf F\cdot {\rm d}\mathbf x \\
&=-\int_0^xkx\,{\rm d}x \\
&=\frac{1}{2}kx^2
\end{align}

I don't understand why we have to set the limits $[0,\,x]$. When deriving kinetic energy, for example, it is enough to merely substitute $F$ but here you need to substitute $F$ and set limits, why?

Comment: -1. Unclear. What other limits would you expect to use instead of [0,x]? Integrals require limits.

Comment: Do you know how the calculation of work (shown in your question) is related to spring potential energy? Do you know the definition of potential energy?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327303/25301

Answer (score 2):

Basically you calculate the work needed to extend the spring from 0 to $x$. This work corresponds to the (potential) energy stored in the spring due to the extension.

You could as well calculate the work needed to extend from some arbitrary fixed $x_0$ to $x$ and you would get the same result shifted by a constant term $\frac{1}{2}kx_0^2$. Potential energy is only defined up to a constant. When you do calculations all that enters will be derivatives of the potential so constants will disappear.

For convenience you can take $x_0=0$ and you are left with the relevant part, i.e. the $x$-dependence of the potential.

PS: When deriving the kinetic energy you should have the same, because according to the work-energy theorem the work done should be equal to the *change* in kinetic energy:

$$\int m\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{dr}=m\int\frac{\mathbf{dv}}{\textrm{dt}}\cdot\mathbf{dr}\\
=m\int_{v_0}^{v} \mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{dv}\\
=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2$$